# How do I turn off background processing with SQL server data tools in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, sqlproj

I am using Visual studio 2013 with the SQL data tools (SSDT) with SQL project.

When I open the project then every time it will checking some background models and showing the message like this "Verifying your model is synchronized with your source files. Your database projects will be ready after 1106 operations are competed"

As far as I can tell I'm not doing anything to explicitly kicking off this verification so I assume that is doing some sort of background compilation/processing/whatever.

If there is a big database then it will taking too much time and I need to wait for complete this.

Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: That's working as designed in this case. It's checking for consistency in the files to make sure that everything still works and that you don't have any broken references due to changes made outside of the project or files that are now missing. I'm not aware of any way to turn that off or disable it.

Comment: Thanks peter for your reply. I have tried different sources to find the turned off but could not find yet. If you find then let me know at any point of time.